# Can I just put my javascript right next to my <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have some javascript/jQuery acting on a particular div inside  tags (for an animation), can I just put the javascript (in a src="link-to-my-js.js" file) right next to my div?

I mean something like the following:

```
<body>
<div id="special">Some html</div>
<script type="text/javascript">javascript related to my div tag above...</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Nope, has to go in a script tag.

Comment: Have you tried it?  If not, I know how you can answer your own question...

Comment: Re: Original version of question -- It depends on if you're asking about `<div id="mydiv"></div>js('mydiv')` or `<div id="mydiv"></div><script>js('mydiv')</script>`. Please provide a code sample of what you're proposing. It also makes a difference if you're asking if it's *reasonable* to put scripts beside tags or if you're asking if you *can*. If you improve the question you will get better answers and possibly more street cred. :)

Comment: @why do you want to keep next to div , you can put it anywhere in the page

Comment: Sorry I just made the edit above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whereever you add your code wrap it with document .ready.

It will wait till all the dom is ready, so you will be safe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put them anywhere you want, *but*

- For performance reasons, it's best to put them [at the bottom of the page](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).
- DOM manipulation before the page has loaded can cause problems, especially with IE, for example [this google maps problem](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=837).

Comment: It looks like that bottom-of-page suggestion applies only when the script is external, right? If it's just a script block on the page, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: No, it still applies; it's not just the download, it's the execution as well (which happens when the script tag is parsed).  Keeping it at the bottom ensures that there's minimum delay in rendering the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the  tag anywhere you please. Remember though that if your script tries to act on an element that has not yet been loaded it will fail.

So if your load your script tag before your div and the script isn't activated by an onload event or something similar element will not be found.

On the contrary if the tag appears after the element you can manipulate it as normal.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where you put it if you wrap your code with the `$(function(){/*code here*/})`

reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3